# Selecting fortran compiler for macports

Tags: fortran, macports, pytables

I am trying to install py-tables using macports. I have previously installed hdf5 with fortran. Somewhere something appears to have gone wrong. When I try to run:

```
    port install py-tables +fortran
```

I get the error:

> Error: +fortran requires a fortran compiler to be selected

I do have a fortran compiler in the path. How can I tell macports to select gfortran, which I installed using ports, is default and is in the path?

Comment: Package gcc48 includes gfortran, as command gfortran-mp-4.8

Comment: I have the gcc48 installed and gfortran-mp-4.8 is also there. On top of that ports have created a symlink that points to gfortran-mp-4.8. Somehow I need to tell port to pick that complier when installing hdf5 (or pyt-tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the gfortran variant as well.

```
port install py-tables +fortran +gfortran
```

Comment: thank you. That seems logical. Although I removed conflicting package, I appreciate the response.